# python, "a in b" keyword, how about multiple a's?

Tags: python

My adventures in Python continue and my favorite books are silent again. Python offers a built-in way to test if a variable is inside an iterable object, using the 'in' keyword:

```
if "a" in "abrakadabra" :
  print "it is definitely here"
```

But is it possible to test if more than one item is in the list (any one)?
Currently, I'm using the syntax below, but it is kinda long:

```
if "// @in " in sTxt or "// @out " in sTxt or "// @ret " in sTxt or <10 more>
  print "found."
```

Of course regexes can help, but using regexes will take lots of verbose of code and will
not be as clear as "a in b". Are there any other Pythonic ways?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
alternatives = ("// @in ", "// @out ", "// @ret ")
if any(a in sTxT for a in alternatives):
    print "found"

if all(a in sTxT for a in alternatives):
   print "found all"
```

[`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) and [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) takes an iterable and checks if any/all of them evaluate to a true value. Combine that with a generator expressions, and you can check multiple items.

Comment: I added links to the documentation so S.Lott doesn't downvote you ;) In all seriousness, though, it's encouraged to link to the docs, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 7):

`any(snippet in text_body for snippet in ("hi", "foo", "bar", "spam"))`

Answer (score 6):

If you're testing lots of lines for the same words, it may be faster to compile them as a regular expression.  eg:

```
import  re
words = ["// @in ", "// @out ", "// @ret "] + ["// @test%s " % i for i in range(10)]

my_regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, words)))

for line in lines_to_search:
    if my_regex.search(line):  print "Found match"
```

Some quick timing shows that this is usually faster than the `any(word in theString for word in words)` approach.  I've tested both approaches with varying text (short/long with/without matches).  Here are the results:

```
         { No keywords  } |  {contain Keywords }
         short    long       short    long
regex  : 0.214    27.214     0.147    0.149
any in : 0.579    81.341     0.295    0.300
```

If performance doesn't matter though, the `any()` approach is more readable.

Comment: \o/ It's nice to have benchmarks with a "may be faster to.." claim!

Answer (score 1):

If you want *any* check then you would use this:

```
inthere = False
checks = ('a', 'b')

for check in checks:
    if check in 'abrakadabra':
        inthere = True
        break
```

If you want *all* check out you could use this:

```
inthere = True
checks = ('a', 'b')

for check in checks:
    if check not in 'abrakadabra':
        inthere = False
        break
```

EDIT: Didn't know the more pythonic `any()`. It's probably better to use that on python.

EDIT2: Added break statements, and corrected the *all*-case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [set methods and operators](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
not alternatives.isdisjoint(sTxt)  # for "any"
(alternatives & sTxt) != set()  # Again, the intersection is nonempty
alternatives <= sTxt  # for "all"
```

I think these are easier to read than using the any or all, but have to convert your collections into sets. Since intersection and containment are what you care about, you might consider making them sets in the first place.

Comment: My answer mentions that these objects have to be sets.

Answer (score 1):

This must be an old post, now the simplest way to do it is with a list:

```
a = "some long text which may or may not include bononos or cabbages"
alternatives = ["apple", "banana", "riverdale"]
if a in alternatives:
    print("Hm?")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way in the syntax to do it. However you can use the 'any' function to make it easier as @MizardX and @Benjamin Peterson showed.